# A gender-neutral term for son or daughter?

Tags: single-word-requests, gender-neutral

I am looking for a term that could be used to describe one's offspring* in a gender neutral manner. Normally, female offspring are called daughters and male offspring are called sons. The three terms are can think of to describe an offspring with no gender are:

- Child - implies an age under that of majority
- Adult child - explicitly states an age over that of majority
- Offspring - unlikely to be used in an informal context ("My offpsring just passed a physics exam")

Is there a single term that can be used to describe an offpsring of no or unknown gender without assuming age, in an informal context?

Sample sentence:

> My _______ just passed a physics exam

*I use this term to avoid implying an age (child or adult)

Comment: [1.1. **child**: *A son or daughter* ***of any age.***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/child)

Comment: Could depend a lot on context, too. Try providing the use case. "No. of Children" is a very common expression, free of gender and age. However, other times other phrases may be used.

Comment: Please include a sample sentence showing how the word would be used (put ____ where the word would go) as required by the single-word-requests tag.

Comment: My **get**?  Probably hasn't been common in 100 years,

Comment: @WayfaringStranger That, or thereabouts. The OED says: “In use with reference to humans now (like sense 2b) chiefly Sc., Irish English (northern), Eng. regional (northern), and U.S. regional.”

Answer (score 6):

First of all, I don't agree that *child* necessarily implies a specific age. But I can see why it might be taken that way.

Asking a senior *Do you have a child?* wouldn't sound completely natural.

Interestingly, however, asking them *Do you have any children?* does.

So, for some reason, **children** (in context) has less of an association with youth than **child**.

---

That aside, the most "natural" term, even though not nearly as common, is **descendant**. Granted, however, it can also apply to grandchildren.

By common implication, **heir** could also mean a child of any age (although it has a very specific context—and it need not actually be a blood relative or one of a younger generation.)

Comment: Not my downvote, and it is getting late, but *do you have a child?* seems as natural but perhaps not as likely as *Do you have (any) children?*

Comment: @user I don't find it wrong, I just find it not nearly as common and, therefore, a bit odd.  It may be a personal thing. *This is a picture of my son. Do you have any children yourself?* seems to flow far better for me than *This is a picture of my son. Do you have a child yourself?* Unless it's something specific. *Sons can be a handful. I don't suppose you have a son?* But, in that case, it's *son* that's used, not *child* . . .

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to use both *child* and *kid* to include adults (with *kids* being slightly less formal).  Indeed, [Mari-Lou A's comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/44619/mari-lou-a) links to the Oxford Dictionary entry for "child" which has a definition:

> A son or daughter of any age.
> *‘when children leave home, parents can feel somewhat redundant’*
> <sub>[Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/child)</sub>

Other examples:

> As a parent, you might have mixed feelings about encouraging your child to move out.
> <sub>[WikiHow](https://www.wikihow.com/Get-Your-Adult-Children-to-Move-Out)</sub>
>
> Here are five strategies to nurture the friendship during your kids' 20s and beyond: ...
> <sub>[AARP.org](https://www.aarp.org/home-family/friends-family/info-04-2013/parenting-adult-children-family-relationships.html)</sub>

See also the Wikipedia page for [child](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Child) and the question [Referring to adult-age sons and daughters as children](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/94679/200524).

However, there is ambiguity of "child" also meaning "minor", which we avoid by saying *adult child* or some variant, such as:

> Over a third of these parents said their children cannot afford to live on their own, and more than 77 percent said they don't want their grown children to live with them.
> <sub>[ABC News](https://abcnews.go.com/International/adults-parts-globe-live-home-parents/story?id=55457188)</sub>

However, *adult child* is slightly suggestive of immaturity (along the lines of "an adult that acts like a child").

> Most women/men find this highly unattractive and hence the adult child generally stays single either forever or until they finally do something about their situation and change their life.
> <sub>[Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Adult%20Child)</sub>

It's also possible to circumvent expressing gender by writing e.g.:

> My 22-year-old has returned to live at home, and I couldn’t be happier.
> <sub>[The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2014/oct/22/adult-child-at-home-i-couldnt-be-happier)</sub>

Regarding offspring with no gender, we might append [*agender*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/agender), such as in:

> Full of compassion, love, and many many questions, Libby shares 5 realizations she learned on her journey to understanding her agender child.
> <sub>[Genderqueer.me](https://genderqueer.me/2016/04/14/fv-loving-my-agender-child/)</sub>

where indeed the agender person wrote:

> i am:
> – agender
> – your oldest kid
> – they

Comment: +1 for mentioning that *adult child* can have a negative connotation.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could say, like the old James Thurber cartoon:

> "Why, I Never Dreamed Your Union Had Been Blessed With Issue!"

but that's a bit stilted and recondite and, in this context, a joke.

What most people would likely say to people of child-bearing age:

> Got any kids?

If the prospective parents are older,  you can put it in the past tense:

> Did you ever have kids?

It's a fairly innocuous question, not likely to run off the rails unless you happen to tap into some family tragedy: "My wife can't have children. We tried adopting, but ..."

Answer (score 0):

Progeny, offspring, descendents.  All those mean children, though they're a little formal.

Comment: [Descendant](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/descendant) also includes grandchildren, etc. (and is typically spelled "descend**a**nt").